# Rewrite root access to be served from a sub-domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^$ 2012/index.php   [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/2012%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* 2012/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* 2012/index.php$0 [QSA] #<-- this is wrong here, and gives 500 error
```

I am trying to server all my urls from the 2012 subfolder.

I tried the above script, and it fails for urls like:

`index.php/admin/controller/action?id=123`

which should be resolved from the subfolder
`2012/index.php/admin/controller/action?id=123`

what is wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting to get when you request `index.php/admin/controller/action?id=123`?

Comment: I want that served from `2012/index.php/admin/controller/action?id=123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the URI `/index.php/admin/controller/action?id=123` fails the -f test for `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/2012%{REQUEST_URI}`, and is instead getting rounded up by the last rule: `RewriteRule .* 2012/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]`, turning the URI into `/2012/index.php?q=index.php/admin/controller/action&id=123`. You'll have to add a special case for this because the first condition/rule allows the existing files to be rewritten as-is, and the last condition/rule acts as a "catch-all" (and the very first rule is simply for the special case when the request URI is `/`). Try something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ 2012/index.php   [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/2012%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* 2012/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* 2012/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
```

The new condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php [OR]` will be satisfied if a request is made starting with `/index.php` and the URI gets rewritten as-is into the /2012/ directory. The **[OR]** ensures the previous condition of a direct access be honored.

Comment: There is no turning into `index.php?=q`, that is just bad example there, as I didn't know how to do it. I want that maintained as it was so it should be redirected to `2012/index.php/admin/controller/action?id=123` as in my comment. Your example fails to resolve `index.php/admin`